Show record list after inputFile in visualforce
I have a problem with inputFile and commandButton in visualforce when to try updating list value during upload CSV file. My problem is list value inside PageReference method is not shown and instead use default list from constructor. The following is a brief overview of how I changed the listClr value in the controller
public class CallLineRetentionController {
    
    ...
        
    public CallLineRetentionController() {
        
        ...
        listClr = [SELECT mdmid_owner__c, Policy_No__c, Remark_Description__c, Retention_Status__c FROM Call_Line_Retention__c ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT :validNum];            
        ...
        }
        
    }

    public PageReference uploadFile() {
        
        if (fileContent == null || !fileName.endsWith('.csv')) {
        ...
        }
        listClr = [SELECT mdmid_owner__c, Policy_No__c, Remark_Description__c, Retention_Status__c FROM Call_Line_Retention__c WHERE Policy_No__c IN :pol];
        System.debug(listClr);
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/CallLineRetentionLayout?upload=success&uploadedNum='+uploadedNum+'&validNum='+validNum+'&invalidNum='+invalidNum+'&invalidPolicy='+String.join(invalidPolicyText,',')+'&invalidPolicyStatus='+invalidPolicyStatus);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }

And this is code from visualforce layout:
<apex:page controller="CallLineRetentionController">
    <script>
    function onUpload()
    {
        var ul = document.getElementById('el_loading');
        ul.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="progressBar">
        <apex:actionPoller rerender="progressBar" interval="10" status="counterstatus"/>
    </apex:form> 
    <apex:form id="formCallLine">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Upload Template" for="file"/>
                        <apex:inputFile value="{!fileContent}" contentType="text/plain; charset=UTF-8" filename="{!fileName}" required="true" id="file"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <br/>  
            
            <div align="center">               
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload" action="{!uploadFile}" onclick="onUpload();">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="policyListSection"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
            </div>
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Policy List" id="policyListSection">
                <apex:outputPanel id="clrTable">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listClr}" var="list" style="overflow:auto;width:850px;" border="1" >
                        <apex:column headerValue="Policy No" value="{!list.Policy_No__c}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Remark Description" value="{!list.Remark_Description__c}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Retention Status" value="{!list.Retention_Status__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:outputPanel>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:page>

There are several methods that I have used just to try to change the listClr value which is displayed not from the constructor but from the list inside uploadFile() method, such as using the apex:actionFunction element into adding a new JavaScript function containing the uploadFile method and initializing the rerender attribute but the results are the same (still accessing the value in the default constructor). Anyone might has a solution to this problem?
SOLUTION:
I completed to solved this problem, just add a void method that holds the listClr value and its parameters:
public void getListClr(List<String> policy) {
        listClr = [SELECT mdmid_owner__c, Policy_No__c, Remark_Description__c, Retention_Status__c FROM Call_Line_Retention__c WHERE Policy_No__c IN :policy];
    }

And this updating from visualforce page:
            <div align="center">               
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload" action="{!uploadFile}" onclick="onUpload();">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="policyListSection"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
            </div>
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Policy List" id="policyListSection">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listClr}" var="list" style="overflow:auto;width:850px;" border="1" >
                    <apex:column headerValue="Policy No" value="{!list.Policy_No__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Remark Description" value="{!list.Remark_Description__c}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Retention Status" value="{!list.Retention_Status__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>    
            </apex:pageBlockSection>


pageRef.setRedirect(true) forces the page to lose its view state. To retain your view state, do not redirect. Note: if you don't need to redirect, you can use the void data type to indicate that the action method does not redirect.
public void uploadFile() {
...


That's work, but i need a return value in PageReference to store information about total of records uploaded from csv file. All parameters from page reference are sets in constructor and the problem is I need a pol value from this method for listClr parameter

@IchwanSholihin If you don't redirect, the system uses the same view state whenever possible, so just setting the variables you need to set should be sufficient.
